# Shiny renderPrint don't capture all console output

Tags: r, shiny, jags

I am trying to display the results from a JAGS model in my Shiny app. The functions show a progress bar in the console when called. I would like to display a summary of the results only and not the loading bars, but renderPrint automatically captures all output to the console. I tried putting the functions into separate reactive functions, but it doesn't change the outcome.

I attached an example app that has this problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(rjags)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("App"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          checkboxGroupInput("studies", "Studies to include:",
                             c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), selected = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))
        ),

        mainPanel(
          verbatimTextOutput("summary")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  data_lumped <- data.frame(
    study = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
    Drug1 = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4),
    n1 = c(2700, 3500, 50, 40, 400, 160, 70, 10),
    mean1 = c(0.65, 0.71, 0.77, 0.8, 0.63, 0.87, 0.67, 0.91),
    sd1 = c(1.31, 0.76, 3.22, 0.54, 0.66, 1.07, 0.61, 0.42),
    Drug2 = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1),
    n2 = c(2700, 3500, 60, 40, 6000, 150, 70, 10),
    mean2 = c(0.95, 0.93, 1.04, 0.66, 0.69, 1.1, 1.03, 1.05),
    sd2 = c(1.3, 0.7, 2.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.94, 0.1)
  )
  
  data.lumped <- reactive({
    
    data <- data_lumped %>% filter(study %in% input$studies)
    ns <- length(data$study)
    list(m = structure(.Data = c(data$mean1, data$mean2 ),
                       .Dim = c(ns, 2)),
         e = structure(.Data = c(data$sd1/sqrt(data$n1), data$sd2/sqrt(data$n2)),
                       .Dim = c(ns, 2)),
         ns = ns,
         na = rep(2, ns),
         nt = 5,
         t = structure(.Data = c(data$Drug1, data$Drug2),
                       .Dim = c(ns, 2)), 
         maxarms = 2
    )
  })

  output_bayes <- reactive({

        ns <- data.lumped()$ns
        init <-list(list(d = c(NA, rep(0,4)), sd = 0.1, mu = rep(0, ns)),
                    list(d = c(NA, rep(1,4)), sd = 0.5, mu = rep(-1, ns)),
                    list(d = c(NA, rep(-1,4)), sd = 0.01, mu = rep(1, ns)))
        modelstring = "
    model{

    # setting values for baseline in contrast
    d[1] <- 0
    tau <- pow(sd, -2)

    # setting prior for mu, delta, d, and sd
    sd ~ dunif(0,5)


    # treatment specific priors
    for(k in 2:nt){
      d[k] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
    }

    for(i in 1:ns){
    # study-specific inital values
      delta[i,1] <- 0
      w[i,1] <- 0
    # prior for study-specific parameters
      mu[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)

    for(k in 1:na[i]){ # per study-specific trial-arm k
          theta[i, k] <- mu[i] + delta[i, k]
          m[i, k] ~ dnorm(theta[i, k], prec[i, k])
          prec[i, k] <- 1 / (e[i, k] * e[i, k])

          dev[i,k] <- (m[i,k]-theta[i,k])*(m[i,k]-theta[i,k])*prec[i,k] #Deviance contribution

    }
    resdev[i] <- sum(dev[i, 1:na[i]])

    for(k in 2:na[i]){
      delta[i,k] ~ dnorm(md[i,k], taud[i,k])
      md[i,k] <- d[t[i,k]] - d[t[i,1]] + sw[i,k]
      taud[i,k] <- tau*2*(k-1)/k
      w[i,k] <- (delta[i,k] - d[t[i,k]] + d[t[i,1]])
      sw[i,k] <- sum(w[i, 1:(k-1)])/(k-1)
    }

    }
    totresdev <-  sum(resdev[])
    meanmu <- mean(mu[])

    # Pad ragged arrays to allow them to be monitored
    for(i in 1:ns){
    for(k in (na[i]+1):maxarms){
    dev[i,k] <- 0
    rhat[i,k] <- 0
    }
    }
    }"
    model <- jags.model(textConnection(modelstring),
                        data = data.lumped(),
                        inits = init,
                        n.chains = 3,
                        n.adapt = 40000)
    update(model, n.burn = 40000)

    samples <- coda.samples(model = model,
                           variable.names = c("d[1]","d[2]", "d[3]", "d[4]",
                                              "d[5]",
                                              "sd", "totresdev"
                           ),

                           n.iter = 400000,
                           thin = 10)
    summary(samples)
      })
  
  sumtext <- reactive(
    output_bayes()
    )
  
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    sumtext()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you could do:

1. Specify `progress.bar='none'` to the calls to `update` and `coda.samples` (see the help file for `?update.jags` for more details on that)
2. Wrap the `library(rjags)` call in `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rjags))` to stop any output occurring there
3. Use `capture.output` to capture/swallow the output manually (although this should not be necessary).

Hope that helps!

Matt